# Understanding the use of Super to access Superclass members

Tags: java, super

I was referring to the java language specification to understand the use of super. While I understand the first use case i.e.

> The form `super.Identifier` refers to the field named Identifier of the current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of the superclass of the current class.

I can't seem to understand the following use case:

> The form `T.super.Identifier` refers to the field named Identifier of the lexically enclosing instance corresponding to `T`, but with that instance viewed as an instance of the superclass of `T`.

Could someone please explain this with the help of code?

I suppose the following could be illustrative of the second case:

```
class S{
    int x=0;
}

class T extends S{
    int x=1;
    class C{
        int x=2;
        void print(){

            System.out.println(this.x);
            System.out.println(T.this.x);
            System.out.println(T.super.x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        T t=new T();
        C c=t.new C();
        c.print();
    }
}
```

output: 
2
1
0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it applies to this situation

```
public class Main {
    static class Child extends Parent{
        class DeeplyNested {
            public void method() {
                Child.super.overriden();
            }
        }

        public void overriden() {
            System.out.println("child");
        }
    }
    static class Parent {
        public void overriden() {
            System.out.println("parent");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Child child = new Child();
        DeeplyNested deep = child.new DeeplyNested();
        deep.method();
    }
}
```

In the JLS

> The form T.super.Identifier refers to the field named Identifier of
>   the lexically enclosing instance corresponding to T, but with that
>   instance viewed as an instance of the superclass of T.

`Identifier` is `overriden`, the method.

Here, the `lexically enclosing instance` is of type `Child` and its superclass is `Parent`. So `T.super` refers to the instance of `Child` viewed as `Parent`.

The code above prints

```
parent
```